# Submitting pyspark job programmatically without using submit pyspark, in python

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, spark-submit

I want to submit spark job from my local system, to remote server where cloudera is installed(Spark on YARN).
Have tried all the possibilities.

Trying to create SparkSession and SparkContext

The following is the code:

1)--------------------------------------------------

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

appName = 'TEST_ON_SPARK'
masterUrl = 'yarn'

spark = None
try:
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(appName).master(masterUrl).\
    config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.XX.XX:8020").\
    config("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "192.168.XX.XX:8032").getOrCreate() 

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise e
finally:
    if spark is not None:
        spark.stop()

##################Also, tried


try:
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(masterUrl).\
    set("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.XX.XX").\
    set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", "192.168.XX.XX").\
    set("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster").\
    set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "192.168.XX.XX:8032").\
    set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", "resourcemanager.192.168.XX.XX").\
    set("spark.yarn.access.namenodes", "hdfs://192.168.XX.XX:8020,hdfs://192.168.XX.XX:8020").\
    set("spark.yarn.stagingDir", "hdfs://192.168.XX.XX:8020/user/username.surname/")
    for i in conf.getAll():
        print(i)
    print(1)
    sparkContext = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    print(2)
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise e
finally:
    if spark is not None:
        spark.stop()
    if sparkContext is not None:
        sparkContext.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For now spark submit is the way to submit the job programmatically